# Ejecting CD from Mac after fresh install?

Tags: startup, recovery, eject

I just installed Lion on a Mac Mini, and I can't get the CD to eject.  Currently, the computer boots up to the "Welcome" screen for new installs, where the Country/Region is selected.  I want to leave it at this point because I'm selling the machine, but want to eject the disk.

When booting up, I've tried several keyboard shortcuts, but none of them are working:

- "C" -- to boot of the CD
- "Cmd + Option + F + O" -- to bo into firmware mode where a cd can be ejected with a command
- holding down the left-mouse button
- "option" -- supposed to eject the disk
- "Cmd + R" -- should go to the recovery console

I'm using a wireless keyboard, which wasn't having a problem loading up Cmd+R menu before I did install.  I'm guessing the "Welcome" screen is bypassing all other commands.  Seems weird though.  I wonder if my wireless keyboard decided to start delaying when it connects with the computer.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it was the wireless (pc) keyboard.  Instead of holding Cmd+R, I pushed it rapidly, and finally it registered (didn't the first 10 times) :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push F12 to eject!

http://www.faqforge.com/macosx/how-to-eject-a-cd-in-a-mac-mini-with-pc-keyboard-and-mouse/

Answer (score 4):

In the past when I have had issues with discs not ejecting I would restart holding option until a screen is displayed that will ask to boot from either the CD or the internal HDD, without making a selection hit the eject key. Then you can shut the computer down then.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, Macs with DVD drives had a small hole by the side that you could stick an unfolded paperclip into, which would mechanically force eject the disk.

From a quick Google of photos, the 2010 Mini (the last with DVD drive) does seem to have such a hole.